# Got an issue when change syntax window to metro window by using MahApps.Metro

Tags: powerbuilder, mahapps.metro

Anyone know what the problem is with the issue I found?
I am using Powerbuilder.net and MahApp.Metro(I still new with it).
But it is working fine when I am using VS 2010.
 Actually my problem is I don't know here to change from Window to MetroWindow in code behind

Here my Design and Xaml:
[image]
Here the issue(Exception) I found:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Guess you missed the MainWindow.cs code behind.
Check this link:
http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#styling_a_window

And you may have to refer to the PowerBuilder.Net help to find the corresponding .cs file.

==Content from the link==

Once MahApps.Metro is installed,
open up MainWindow.xaml

add a namespace reference in the opening Window tag:
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"

change

You’ll need to change the codebehind (MainWindow.xaml.cs, right-click the designer and select ‘View source’) so that the inherited class matches the XAML, so

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

becomes

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
```

Comment: that syntax working for wpf if I am using VS but the problem is how to change from Window to MetroWindow in Powerbuilder